# Problem adding Mapbox Tile Layer in Forge Viewer

Tags: mapbox, autodesk-forge, forge

I have started learning GIS development with Geodjango, mapbox and Openlayers. I have created my application in Autodesk Forge Viewer and I have been able to create the bucket and added some 3D models. Now I am facing a problem of adding a mapbox Tile layer underneath the 3D model inside Forge-Viewer. Any assistance will be appreciated. Here is my Javascript code

```
class MyMapboxForgeExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
    }
    quad(x,y) {
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 256, 256 ),
            new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({ color:0xa0a0a0, depthWrite:false, 
                map: (THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/snex-tech/cl9ie4t7h00kv15qrta7poy29.html?title=view&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic25leC10ZWNoIiwiYSI6ImNsOWZqbnV6bzAyMDQzd29hNXk2cWgwOHAifQ.-qMPioM3OUUHLWgClmsthw&zoomwheel=true&fresh=true#2/37.75/-92.25`)) })
        );
        mesh.position.set (x*256,y*256, 1);
        return mesh;
    }

    load() {
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, ()=>{
            if (!this.viewer.overlays.hasScene('map')) {
                this.viewer.overlays.addScene('map');
            }
            const tiles = new THREE.Object3D();
            tiles.position.set(-1140,-800, -10);
            tiles.scale.set(2,2,1);
            const tilex = [-1,0,1,2,3];
            const tiley = [0,1,2];
            tilex.map( x => {
                tiley.map( y => {
                    tiles.add(this.quad(x,y));
            })});
            window.tiles=tiles;
            this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(tiles, 'map');
        });
        return true;
    }
    unload() {
        return true;
    }
}
Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MyMapboxForgeExtension', MyMapboxForgeExtension);
```

I tried creating a style in Mapbox and linking the mapbox api in my Javascript code but the map is not reflecting underneath the 3D model in Autodesk Forge Viewer. Below is my ForgeViewer.js;

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

https://gist.github.com/wallabyway/4503609e84a2b612b27138abba8aa3b7

This is the simplest way of adding a map tile to the viewer scene.
It actually adds a small grid of tiles to the scene.

If you want something more advanced, then use geoThree.js.  I wrote a blog post on it here:

BLOG: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-mapbox-google-maps-forge-viewer

[image: adding tiles]

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I have tried using the first link, I am able to add a map using mapbox API but now the issue is the map is not covering all the areas taken by the 3D model and the the map is on top of the 3D model instead of being underneath it.

Comment: Try lifting the Z value in the THREE quad mesh object. .. this line… https://gist.github.com/wallabyway/4503609e84a2b612b27138abba8aa3b7#file-googlemaps-ext-js-L29